# Hibernate 5.0 dialect auto detection not working with JNDI on Tomcat

Tags: hibernate, tomcat, jdbc, jndi

I'am trying to connect to a JNDI datasource specified in Tomcat's server.xml.
My hibernate.cfg.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">java:comp/env/jdbc/myDB</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext</property>
        <mapping class="com.gigatronik.bosch.plugin.remoteserver.db.ConnectEntity"/>
    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Everything works well (so I assume my configuration is correct) until I remove the `hibernate.dialect` property - which implicitly enables dialect auto detection:

```
WARN [http-apr-8080-exec-9] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
```

and

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:100) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.5.Final.jar:5.0.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.5.Final.jar:5.0.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:137) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.5.Final.jar:5.0.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.5.Final.jar:5.0.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.5.Final.jar:5.0.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.5.Final.jar:5.0.5.Final]
... 78 more
```

With Jetty the auto discovery feature works very well. Seems like only Apache Tomcat has this problem. How to enable auto detection with Tomcat?

**Update:**
My Tomcat configuration:

```
...
<GlobalNamingResources>
...

<Resource name="jdbc/myDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
driverClassName="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" 
url="jdbc:derby:myDB;create=true"
maxTotal="100" maxIdle="30" maxWaitMillis="10000" />
...
</GlobalNamingResources>
```

Comment: I assume you have configured 'java:comp/env/jdbc/myDB' in tomcat, as you reference it in your hibernate config, but don't quote it in your description of what you've done? If you did: Let us know how. If you didn't: Do it.

Comment: Auto discovery only works on a direct db connection, not using JNDI. You might be able to store the dialect property as an JNDI value on the server and read it while configuring Hibernate.

Comment: @OlafKock I've updated the initial post with my tomcat config. Is it correct?

Comment: @Stefan But why does it work when using Jetty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found the problem cause:

the ResourceLink within the application's context.xml was not defined. After I additionally defined

```
<Context path="/foo.bar">
    <ResourceLink global="jdbc/myDB" name="jdbc/myDB" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
</Context>
```

the connection finally worked. Event JNDI does work right now. So in fact the comment of @Stefan on my question is simply not correct.

So watch out for hibernate errors that poorly describe the problem cause.